# Spring cloud config failed using filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I'm using [Spring Cloud](http://spring.io) Config to help **build Rest Services** and I choose [GitHub](https://github.com/) to maintain my config files. There is a need when I change some config on `GitHub` its [WebHooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) will call `API` which Spring Cloud Config provided to monitor configuration change and notify **Config Service**.
   In order to verify whether the request is a `GitHub` request. I will add a filter to check the signature, which does not work:
   The request even doesn't through the filter and get a http 200 ok response. I also test the way to extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. But still got the same. I wonder is spring cloud config do sth before my filter can handle the request?

```
public class WebhookSignatureFilter implements Filter
{
    @Autowired private WebhooksAuthService webhooksAuthService;

    @Override public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
                                   ServletResponse servletResponse,
                                   FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,
                                                                   ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest=(HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;

        String githubSignature=httpServletRequest.getHeader("HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE");
        String payload=getPayLoad(httpServletRequest);
        try
        {
            if(!webhooksAuthService.isValidWebhookSignature(githubSignature, payload))
            {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException();
            }
        }
        catch(GeneralSecurityException e)
        {
            throw new ServletException("verify signature failed!");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private String getPayLoad(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        httpServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;
        StringBuffer payload=new StringBuffer();
        String line;

        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream=httpServletRequest.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                payload.append(line);
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(bufferedReader!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return payload.toString();
    }

    @Override public void destroy()
    {
    }

    @Override public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {
    }
}
```

here is my config file:

```
@Configuration public class FilterConfig
{
    @Bean public FilterRegistrationBean webhooksFilter()
    {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration=new FilterRegistrationBean();
        WebhookSignatureFilter webhookSignatureFilter=new WebhookSignatureFilter();
        registration.setFilter(webhookSignatureFilter);
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/monitor");
        registration.setOrder(0);

        return registration;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What isn't working? Your filter will only be invoked for the `/monitor` url nothing else. But stating it doesn't work isn't enough, be more precies. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some inspiration on writing a good question.

Comment: thank U , i 've already edited the question.

Comment: As stated why should it go through your filter, the only URL that will trigger the filter is `/monitor`.

Comment: yeah , that is what i want. i only want to check /monitor. it's a default url provided by spring cloud config to invoke channels to notify config changes.

Comment: Is it really `/monitor`... As I would suspect that it runs on the management port and url and not the default. It might be that the filter is attached to the default endpoints and not the management side of the application.

Comment: I use postman to do my test, i copy the github webhooks request. i think i post the right url . Because I run the service at localhost, the url is http://localhost:{service-port}/monitor. if i call other url , it will return http 404 status. but when i call /monitor, i add debug point on my filter which expect that the filter will check github signature. but every time the config service even doesn't pass the filter and return 200 status . So i suppose that spring cloud config do sth before my filter can handle that request,

Comment: I never said you aren't calling the right url. The endpoint is a regular controller, so it should pass through the filter. Try adding `/monitor/`* as a URL filter as well. Another thing you can try is setting the `order` to `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` instead of 0. Also make sure that your filter is actually registered.

Comment: eh.....thanks . i have tried your method just now. but it seems still not working.

Comment: I also mentioned that generally the actuator stuff is on the management side of the app, a different http connector. Make sure that the filter registers with the right one (not sure how to but alas). And as asked does it actually gets created/registered .

Comment: I think i registered that filter. for i use spring boot to build my app. i saw the register log when i start it. And i have already got a success case when i develop another spring cloud project(you know spring cloud have many sub project,such as gateway, stream etc). I copy almost the same code from the gateway (i used filter success on that project). but it doesn't work on this config project. i don't know why..

Comment: Could you please share your application.properties or application.yml so that we can identify using which port you can invoke the request. Also in the filterchain do you have your filter?I know it's a stupid question but just check in the filter chain whether you have your filter?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I found that when I checked  the application.yml. I originally config rabbitmq ,github config mixed in the same yml file . So it may caused by the confuse yml file which may lead some config not loaded.